# Need schema for school grading system

Tags: sql, hibernate, schema

I'm new to SQL and am attempting to create a DB schema usable with Hibernate but am worried about scaling issues, data access and best way to query data.

Project:
School grading system

**Background:**
Want to store all assignments, but if we project a school having 4000 students each with ~182 days of class.  If there is a graded assignment per day (in class + homework) then each can have 182 x 6 x 4000 means there are ~4.3M grades per school year.  ~43.7M in 10 years.

I should be able to display all assignments per quarter and current grade.  I should also be able to get these for any year I attended school (1Q at a time).  Teachers and admin should be able to retrieve from all stored history (again 1Q at a time).

**Questions:**

**Q1 Scalability**
Will there be a performance issue?
Is there any issue with a table growing to 100M entries?

**Data access:**
Is there a better way to split up the data?
Thinking of retrieving grade data per student on id between dates (thus quarters) which is in assignments.  Should I add another column for quarterID and make a table to store them?

**Access Grades:**
What is the best way to query for a students quarter grades?

- Grade[] getStudentGrades( studentid, startdate, enddate )

Naturally it would go along with

- Assignment[] getAssignmentDetails( Grade[] grades )

I am aware that these two can be joined in another class GradedAssignment using a SQL join statment:

- GradedAssignment[] getStudentGradedAssignement( studentid, startdate, enddate )

**Does this schema seem right?**
 (Added updates from below)
NOTE: I omitted for brevity many table columns.

> **Student**
>    - **studentid** (PK)
>
> **StudentClass** (Ref table)
>    - classid (FK)
>    - studentid (FK)
>
> **Teacher**
>    - **teacherid** (PK)
>
> **TeacherClass** (Ref table)
>    - **teacherid** (PK)
>    - classid
>
> **Grades**  (The only primary key I could think of is compound with assignmentid+studentid)
>    - assignmentid (FK)
>    - grade
>    - classid
>    - studentid (FK)
>
> **Assignment**
>    - **assignmentid** (PK)
>    - teacherid (FK)
>    - pointsPossible
>    - assignDate
>    - dueDate
>    - name
>    - description

**What is the best way to access grades?**

- SELECT Assignment.pointsPossible, Assignment.name, Grade.grade FROM Grade,Assignment WHERE grade.studentid=:id AND Grade.assignmentid == Assignment.assignmentid AND Assignment.assignDate < :dateFinish AND Assignment.assignDate > :dateStart;

or use a JOIN???

- SELECT Assignment.pointsPossible, Assignment.name, Grade.grade FROM Grade LEFT JOIN Assignment on assignmentid WHERE grade.studentid=:id AND Assignment.assignDate < :dateFinish AND Assignment.assignDate > :dateStart;

Comment: Is this supposed to be a schema of database tables?

Comment: Very loosely speaking yes.  Just enough to get the idea of whats going on across.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the dynamics of a school I think there have to be a few additions to your schema. e.g. students pass from one class to another class every year. Those conditions must also be considered to build a sustainable application.

I think a good schema would be -

**Student**

- studentid (primary key)
- firstname
- lastname
- date_of_birth
- .... (all other basic personal information needed for the record)

**StudentClass**

- studentid (foreign key references student.studentid)
- classid (foreign key refernces class.classid)
- admissiondate
- ... (all other information related to admission or promotion of a student to a class)

**Class**

- classid (primary key)
- classname
- ... (all other information related to a class)

**TeacherClass**

- teacherid (foreign key references teacher.teacherid)
- classid (foreign key references class.classid)
- assigndate
- releasedate
- ...

**Teacher**

- teacherid (primary key)
- firstname
- lastname
- qualification
- date_of_birth
- ...

**Assignment**

- assignmentid (primary key)
- assigning_teacherid (foreign key references teacher.teacherid)
- pointsPossible
- assignDate
- dueDate
- name
- description
- ...

**Grade**

- assignmentid (fk)
- classid (fk)
- studentid (fk)
- grade
- ...

You are right about the compound primary key on (assignmentid, studentid) which are also foreign keys.

Comment: I did leave a LOT out to simplify potential schema.  I tried to leave just a few fields of interest for inter-table relationships.  Other tables were ommitted for brevity.  I notced that relationship links such as StudentClass and TeachClass were included.  Since grades table would be HUGE.  How would you handle it?

Comment: Perhaps by tuning your queries and your database sever too. Make sure there are relationship links between tables that you are going to join. These will not just help you enforce integrity constraints but also can give you better performances with indexes on all FKs.

Comment: So the schema seems like its o the right track.  What about the scalability and best way to access.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot help you with scalability and ways to acces. I'm not deep into hibernate.

Comment: Well I thank you for basic schema validation of it being on the right track.  I think Hibernate would have created the Student/TeachClass tables for the Many relationships.